# Create an iterative table for react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So, im working on a web app to help parents track their children's vaccination schedule. For that I may need some type of table where operations can occur in the cell level, for example clicking in a cell and show a place to set the vaccine as taken and reflect that in the specific cell of the dose of that vaccine and set it as green. Is there a library or anything that can help me accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

react-table offers headless utilities for managing your tables state. Here is an example implementing editable data. [Link](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/editable-data)